# Google Domains redirecting website

Tags: domains, dns, google-domains

I bought a domain using Google Domains (let's call it newdomain.com). I also own olddomain.com (bought via register.com) which is hosted on a dedicated server I'm paying for.

I bought newdomain.com from Google so as to take advantage of the email functionality. I would however like to point newdomain.com to the olddomain.com server so that I can create a new site there.

Is there any way I can do this without losing Google's email functionality?

I've tried using the redirection function, but this is a simple redirection, meaning that anybody typing in newdomain.com will actually see olddomain.com in the URL bar while I want them to keep seeing newdomain.com.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Do you realise you don't need to purchase a domain from Google to use Gmail for the domain? All you need to do is point the appropriate DNS records (Mainly MX records) to gmail? Similarly, for web the only thing DNS does is resolve a domain to an IP. The web server needs to be configured to reply with data appropriate to the domain name.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an alias very easily:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

### EDIT: In case that link changes or is removed here are the basic steps to make an alias. See link for additional resources (from Google)

**Send emails from a different address or alias**

If you own another email address, you can send mail as that address. For example:

Yahoo, Outlook, or other non-Gmail address
Your work, school, or business domain or alias, like @yourschool.edu or youralias@gmail.com
Another Gmail address
Tip: You can send emails from up to 99 different email addresses.

**Step 1: Add an address you own**

- On your computer, open Gmail. In the top right, click **Settings**
  and then **See all settings**.
- Click the **Accounts and import** or **Accounts tab**. In the "Send mail as"
  section, click **Add another email address**.
- Enter your name and the address you want to send from. Click **Next
  Step** and then **Send verification**.
- For school or work accounts, enter the SMTP server (for example,
  smtp.gmail.com or smtp.yourschool.edu) and the username and password on that account
- Click **Add Account**

**Step 2: Confirm the address**

- Sign in to the account you added
- Open the confirmation message you got from Gmail
- Click the link

**Step 3: Change the "From" address**

- In the message, click the "From" line. (If you don't see this, click
  the space next to the recipient's email.)
- Select the address to send from

### **Set up Email Forwarding on the Domain**

- From Google Domains, go to Mail and then look for **Email Forwarding**
- Click on **Add email** next to the desired domain, type in the alias you want to create, and enter the existing email you want to forward to
- Click the **Add** button
- You should get a message about the setup, check your Gmail inbox for that when done

Comment: I like this approach (I hadn't thought of it), but this assumes I have already setup email for newdomain.com somewhere, which is something I was hoping to avoid. Is it possible to set up GMail for an address I own but for which I haven't set up email?

Comment: @AdrienHingert You don't need to have email set up for it to work. I've added more instructions to my answer to help with this.

Comment: @Mike Ciffone, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the instructions say "Sign in to the account you added. Open the confirmation message you got from Gmail" This sounds to me like you need to have the email setup, or am I missing something

Comment: @AdrienHingert you replied quicker than I could type it out lol. Let me know if you still need help

Comment: @AdrienHingert if you have the forwarder set up before you do the verification, the verification email will end up in gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I want to build on Mike's answer.  What he explains will work, but there will be an unintended side effect that may or may not be desirable.

If you set up an email account `you@example.com` and then forward that to gmail, following the steps above will work.  However not only will you get all your emails to gmail, but they will be accumulating in the server mailbox.  If you don't pay attention to that you may fill that mailbox.

**A solution** is to create an email account that is just used by google SMTP e.g. `outgoing@example.com` and use that at gmail.  So you end up with that email account, which will never receive any incoming, plus `you@example.com` as a forwarder.

Bonus solution: If you are a bit lazy and have too many passwords, use your gmail address as your `outgoing@example.com` password ;o)

Comment: Great add, Steve. If this is the case, an alias can be ok as a quick fix until SMTP is configured.